# In Postgres, is it possible to insert a constant combined with the result of SELECT?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example suppose I have a table TRADES as follows

DATE, PRICE, ...

I wish to construct a table TRADING_DAYS as follows

MARKET, DATE

With sample data as follows

```
NYSE, 2011-03-03
NYSE, 2011-03-04
NYSE, 2011-03-05
```

Is it possible to write a query that extracts DATE from TRADES, combines it with the constant 'NYSE' and inserts into TRADING_DAYS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TRADING_DAYS 
SELECT 'NYSE', DATE
FROM TRADES
```

But I guess you want the distinct dates rather then duplicates?

```
INSERT INTO TRADING_DAYS 
SELECT DISTINCT 'NYSE', DATE
FROM TRADES
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TRADING_DAYS SELECT 'NYSE', DATE FROM TRADES
```